# Allow overriding of object method during __init__ by accepting replacement function as argument

Tags: python

Say I have a class (`Rectangle`) which implements a method (`describe`) as follows:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def describe(self):
        return 'Rectangle with height {:0.2f} and width {:0.2f}'.format(float(self.height),
                                                                        float(self.width))
```

This works as expected:

```
r = Rectangle(5, 3)
r.describe()
>>> 'Rectangle with height 5.00 and width 3.00'
```

I would like to be able to specify, at instantiation, an alternative function which would take the place of `describe`.  I believe the below works:

```
import functools as ft

class RectangleEnhanced(object):
    def __init__(self, height, width, description_function=None):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        if description_function is None:
            self.describe = self.default_describe
        else:
            self.describe = ft.partial(description_function, self)

    def default_describe(self):
        return 'Rectangle with height {:0.2f} and width {:0.2f}'.format(float(self.height),
                                                                        float(self.width))
```

So that:

```
s = RectangleEnhanced(5, 3)
s.describe()
>>> 'Rectangle with height 5.00 and width 3.00'
```

continues to work as before, but, in addition:

```
def area_description(enh_rect):
    return 'Rectangle with area {:0.2f}'.format(float(enh_rect.height * enh_rect.width))

t = RectangleEnhanced(5, 3, area_description)
t.describe()
>>> 'Rectangle with area 15.00'
```

Is this a reasonable approach to this problem?  I can't imagine that I'm the first person to want to do this, and so I'm nervous that the approach below is suboptimal/unpythonic/bad/etc.  Is there a "right" way to handle this?

---

Edit

Here's an example closer to my use case:

```
class FilterableCollection(object):
    def __init__(self, items, owner, purpose, filterfunc=None):
        self.items = set(items)
        self.owner = owner
        self.purpose = purpose
        if filterfunc is None:
            self.filterfunc = lambda x: True
        else:
            self.filterfunc = ft.partial(filterfunc, self)

    def filtered(self):
        return filter(self.filterfunc, self.items)

items = ['fun_ball', 'boring_ball', 'fun_bear', 'boring_bear']
owner = 'Bill'
purpose = 'fun'

f = FilterableCollection(items, owner, purpose)
print f.filtered()

def is_applicable(self, item):
    return self.purpose in item
g = FilterableCollection(items, owner, purpose, is_applicable)
print g.filtered()
```

which returns:

```
['fun_bear', 'fun_ball', 'boring_ball', 'boring_bear']
['fun_bear', 'fun_ball']
```

as expected.  So the idea is that when you create a specific instance of a `FilterableCollection` you can create a custom filter (which may depend on other attributes of that particular `FitlerableCollection`) which is then available to be called whenever.  So there might be 10 `FilterableCollections` floating around, and they can each be filtered with their respective filters by calling the `.filtered` method.

I'm very open to the idea of doing this with inheritance or any other technique.  But how would that apply in this case?

Comment: It is a little unusual to want to specify that per *instance*.  Why do you want to do that instead of making a subclass that has an additional description method?

Comment: this question may be too opinion based. however, I would say that you would probably want to instead just make a separate, inherited class that has a different describe function

Comment: What, you mean like in my answer?

Comment: My actual use case is a bit more complicated than this.  The essence is that for each instance of the class, I want to be able to perform a certain kind of filtering on some data attached to the instance. Depending on the context, the kind of filtering required could vary widely.  Hence it's not really possible to parameterize the filtering function and have it just take a few arguments.  Instead, I wanted to make it possible to write a filtering function (which would have access to attributes of the instance) and then have that appropriate filtering function available to call on each instance

Comment: Since `default_describe()` is going to be available even if you provide a different `description_function` I don't see what this approach accomplishes aside from muddying up what your class does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The essence is that for each instance of the class, I want to be able
>   to perform a certain kind of filtering on some data attached to the
>   instance. Depending on the context, the kind of filtering required
>   could vary widely.

What you describe here is known as the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), and your example implementation is almost as pythonic as possible - Python functions being objects, quite a few design patterns requiring a full blown "functor" class in most mainstream languages are implemented with a plain function in Python.

The only "improvement" I can see would be to get rid of the partial - Python functions do know how to become instance methods:

```
    if description_function is None:
        self.describe = self.default_describe
    else:
        self.describe = description_function.__get__(self)
```

You can read this for more about this behaviour : https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod

Not that this would change anything from a purely functional (no pun intended) but it will certainly make you look as a PythonGuru(tm)

Comment: I looked at your second link, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the meaning of `description_function.__get__(self)`.  What is this voodoo? :)

Comment: It's how Python internally uses the descriptor protocol (which is the underlying mechanism for all computed attributes in Python) to turn functions into methods. Read about the descriptor protocol and play with it, it's a very important part of Python's object system (this and metaclasses). And there's really no voodoo here, just a very smart use of a couple simple concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Your *implementation* makes sense. It is common for a class to *take an optional param* in its `__init__` and to use a senisble default value if it isn't being passed. In your case *that parameter is a function*.

So this is a good implementation given you really **really** want to do that.

However, like many other commentator point out, this doesn't sound like a very good idea.  The difference between taking a simple value and taking a function to override a method like this, is that the function param affects the *behavior* of the instance.  **Instances of the same type shouldn't really have different behavior.**

Therefor using different types (e.g. using inheritance), is the most straightforward approach.

---

Since you asked, here is how you can use inheritance here:

```
class FilterableCollection(object):
    def __init__(self, items, owner, purpose):
        self.items = set(items)
        self.owner = owner
        self.purpose = purpose

    def filtered(self):
        return self.items

class ApplicabilityFilterableCollection(FilterableCollection):
    def filtered(self):
        return [ item for item in self.items if self.purpose in item ]

f = FilterableCollection(items, owner, purpose)
print f.filtered()
g = ApplicabilityFilterableCollection(items, owner, purpose)
print g.filtered()
```

Comment: Ever heard of the strategy pattern ? Inheritance is just a restricted (and vastly overrated) form of composition / delegation. Instances of a same type should (preferably...) have the same *interface*, but there's nothing wrong with a parametized behaviour.

Comment: I added a richer example above which might make my goals clear.  Let me know what you think!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers nowhere in my answer did I write "you should use inheritance". As my answer makes clear, my opinion is that it's best to use different types for different behaviors, and inheritance is just an example of a simple way of defining different types here

Comment: @shx2, could you offer an alternative construction (of, say, the `FilteredCollection` example above) that shows how to do this task using class inheritance?

Comment: Right, so just to make sure I have the idea...for every filtering rule that might come up, you'd need to make a different class.  I don't really know why, but somehow I think of the act of filtering as being a function, and wanted to be able to write the filtering logic as such and then have a single class implement an arbitrary filter.  But it seems like with inheritance you'd need to spin up a subclass for every filtering rule.  If nothing else, it seems like in that way the subclassing approach would lead to more lines of code.

Comment: @8one6, right. note lines-of-code metric is a poor indicator of code/design quality. However, if you have many filtering functions you want to use, I don't see any problem with your original solution. I would just suggest that you don't over-use this approach, only when you find it more useful than the alternatives.